# How to TDD for Restful client code example

Tags: java, rest, tdd, resteasy, rest-client

I did some TDDs before, but they were just straightforward and simple.

However, I will implement a restful client and invoke a restful API of third parties (Twitter, or Jira).

I used Resteasy client framework to implement that. The code is:

```
public void invokePUT() {
     ClientRequest request =
                 new ClientRequest("http://example.com/customers");
     request.accept("application/xml");
     ClientResponse<Customer> response = request.put(Customer.class); 
     try {
          if (response.getStatus() != 201)
               throw new RuntimeException("Failed!");
     } finally {
          response.releaseConnection(); 
     }}
```

If I want to write a test for this method (should write test before implement this method), what kind of the code should I write.

For GET, I can test the return Entity is equals to my expected entity and for POST, I can test the created entity's id is not null.

But how about for PUT and DELETE. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use [REST Assured](https://github.com/jayway/rest-assured) testing framework. It is great tool for testing REST services. On their website you'll find tons of examples how to use it. Just use it together with JUnit or TestNG to check assertions and you are done.

Answer (score 1):

i would inject mocked classes that test, if put and delete was called as intended (with expected parameters and so on). easymock or similar is good for that
(same with post and get)

EDIT:
in case you want to test the rest client, use dependency injection to inject the request, then use easymock to mock it like this (for example to test, if delete is called properly):

```
@Test void myTest(){
 ClientRequest mock = EasyMock.createMock(ClientRequest.class);
 mock.delete(2); //test if resource with id=2 is deleted or something similar

 EasyMock.replay(mock);
 invokeDelete(mock);
 EasyMock.verify(mock);
}
```

Comment: could you please give some sample code for put and delete? thanks

Comment: i think, i was wrong. i thought, you want to test the method that uses the rest-service. but you meant, you want to test the rest-service itself, didnt you?

Comment: I know how to test the restful service which I write. But I am not quite sure about how to test the code (restful client code) which invoke the third parties' restful service. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I'd go about the problem in the short term:

1) Extract the request into a parameter to the method. `invokePUT()` now becomes:

```
public void invokePUT(ClientRequest request) {
    request.accept("application/xml");
    ClientResponse<Customer> response = request.put(Customer.class); 
    try {
         if (response.getStatus() != 201)
              throw new RuntimeException("Failed!");
    } finally {
         response.releaseConnection(); 
    }
}
```

2) In your test, use a stubbed version of `ClientRequest`

```
@Test
public void sendsPayloadAsXml() {
    StubbedClientRequest request = new StubbedClientRequest(new StubbedResponse());
    restApi.invokePUT(request);
    assertEquals("application/xml", request.acceptHeader);
}

@Test
public void makesTheCallUsingPut() {
    StubbedClientRequest request = new StubbedClientRequest(new StubbedResponse());
    restApi.invokePUT(request);
    assertTrue(request.putWasCalled);
}

@Test
public void releasesTheConnectionWhenComplete() {
    StubbedResponse success = new StubbedResponse();
    StubbedClientRequest request = new StubbedClientRequest(success);
    restApi.invokePUT(request);
    assertTrue(success.connectionWasClosed);
}

@Test(expected = RuntimeException.class)
public void raisesAnExceptionWhenInvalidResponseReceived() {
    StubbedClientRequest request = new StubbedClientRequest(new StubbedResponse(400));
    restApi.invokePUT(request);
}

private static class StubbedClientRequest extends ClientRequest {
    public String acceptHeader = "";
    public boolean putWasCalled;
    public ClientResponse response

    public StubbedRequest(ClientResponse response) {
        this.response = response;
    }

    @Override
    public ClientResponse put(Class klass) {
        putWasCalled = true;
        return response;
    }

    @Override
    public void accept(String header) {
        acceptHeader += header;
    }

}

private static class StubbedResponse extends ClientResponse {
    public boolean connectionWasReleased;
    public int status = 201;

    public StubbedResponse(int status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public StubbedResponse() { }
}
```

This may not be a perfect design (Handing the ClientRequest to the class and having the RestEasy stuff exposed to the outside world) but it's a start.

Hope that helps!

Brandon